# Double Click Tab Bar Icon Does Not Take Me To Root View

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a tab bar app.  Usually, no matter how deep in the navigation heirchy I am in, if I click the tab bar icon for the tab I am already in, it takes me too the highest or root view.

But for some reason, just for 1 of my tabs, this does not happen,  it takes me to the 2nd to hight level view, but not all the way.

Does anyone have any ideas why this may be the case?

Comment: Try Logging the array of view controllers for the problematic UINavigationController i.e. `For ( UIViewController* vc in navController.viewControllers ) NSLog(@"%@",vc);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you implementing another tab bar in this tab? As the popToRoot method may be stopping at this point rather than going to its parent

Comment: No, I am not.  It is the same tab bar throughout the app.

Comment: The view where it is stopping is a sub UIView of the parent view as well, so I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Did you push this view onto the stack using `pushViewCotnroller:animated:`?

Comment: No, I pushed the view using: `[aboutView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [self.view addSubview:aboutView];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        [aboutView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];`